# how to share a wiki

Tags: mediawiki, fileshare

We have created a manual library (MediaWiki) for a system that we have, and we like to expose it to one of the customers.
I googled for a while and found many filesharing sites, but I don't know if that is a good idea, as it won't look "nice". We like to make it something like wikipedia. So what options do we have?

any help is more than appreciated...

Comment: Setup a web server reachable from the Internet loaded with MediaWiki and your data. You will find a PHP+MySQL hosting easily like this one: http://www.siteground.com/mediawiki-hosting.htm (first from Google)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not really clear.

If you want to share the information as it is with the customer. Install MediaWiki on the customer servers. Then, periodically dump your information and push it into the Cusomer's MediaWiki server. MediaWiki back-end is usually a MySQL server, you can easily export that data. This way you can only expose the documentation to the client once you have stable copy.

Answer (score 2):

[Extension Push](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aPush) allows you to push content from your own wiki to a customer's wiki. The extension is currently under heavy development, but should be relatively stable.

Answer (score 1):

You share it by making it accessible to them over the internet. You don't send them files. It's a website. That's the point.

Comment: Your answer is very close to how we are thinking, so could you please advice me to where i can find information on how to share it on the internet with only one customer?

Comment: Well, if it is running as a website, you can just set permissions via your webserver. You'll find someone willing to talk you through how to do this on the "ServerFault" website, or similar.